# encodeURIComponent and encodeURI

Tags: javascript, utf-8, character-encoding

I am trying to encode the French characters inside the URL.

The url is constructed in javascript, and then I use `window.open` to open the url.

For example,

```
var alt_title='Thierry Frémaux: Les confiden'
```

1. `window.open('http://example.com/alt_title'=+encodeURIComponent(altCatTit));`
2. `window.open(encodeURI('http://example.com/alt_title='+encodeURIComponent(altCatTit))`

When **1.** executes, I don't see the French characters being encoded in the new popup's url.

When **2.** executes, I do see them being encoded.

Could you please tell me why do I need to encode them twice in order for them to appear as encoded in the new popup's URL?

Is it the right way of encoding special characters in the URL?

Fixed the typo's sorry!

Comment: The variables in `window.open()` are not the same as the one you assigned, and you're missing quotes around the value in the assignment. Aren't you getting a syntax error for that?

Comment: You don't see encoded characters in the server script because they're automatically decoded before passing the parameters to the script.

Comment: it is hard to understand what is going on because you have pieces of code that do not fit together, and you have a syntax error in the first one.

Comment: You also shouldn't put encoded characters like `%20` in the string if you're planning on encoding it -- they'll get double-encoded (and triple-encoded in **2**).

Comment: What is this about man `=+` ? Just use the `+` !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you looking for this?

```
var s = 'Thierry Frémaux: Les confiden'
var url = 'http://example.com/?alt_title=' + encodeURIComponent(s)
```

Comment: Yes. when I actually do this

window.open('http://example.com/?alt_title=' + encodeURIComponent('Thierry Frémaux: Les confiden'))

These characters don't appear to be encoded in the new popup's url.

é

But when I do this, 

window.open(encodeURI('http://example.com/?alt_title=' + encodeURIComponent('Thierry Frémaux: Les confiden')))

é is encoded properly

Comment: is this because the browser decodes them before displaying? check the HTTP console and see if the request has the correct url.

Comment: Oh I see. So I have to encode the URL twice if I want the characters to show up as encoded in the url?

Comment: Thanks! You are right. They are encoded in the Request Header, and the browser probably decodes it before displaying the url.

Comment: Would encoding twice solve the problem? If I encode twice, the browser will display the encoded URL, then I can "decode" it again when the get parameters are parsed on the server?

Comment: yes, if you encode it twice you would need to decode it on the server.

Answer (score 0):

encodeURIComponent() : assumes that its argument is a portion (such as the protocol, hostname, path, or query string) of a URI. Therefore it escapes the punctuation characters that are used to separate the portionsof a URI.

encodeURI(): is used for encoding existing url